# Laravel 4: Form to upload photos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, image-uploading

Someone can tell me what is the proper way to make a form for photo-upload.
I made this but is not working:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'photos.store'),'image/save', array('files'=> true)) }}

 {{ Form::label('title', 'Title: ') }}
 {{ Form::text('title') }}

 {{ Form::label('caption', 'Caption: ') }}
 {{ Form::textarea('caption') }} 

 {{ Form::label('photo', 'Photo: ') }}
 {{ Form::file('photo') }}

 <br>

 {{ Form::submit('Add Photo', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary' )) }}

 {{ Form::close() }}
```

When in the store method i try to dump dd(Input::file('photo')); 
i obtain null..
That miss that something is missing, or something is wrong in this form.
Someone can help me please?

Or alternatively, how you would make the form?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The method Form::open() of Laravel's form builder accepts only one argument which should be an array.

It is defined in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php`.

I don't know what you want to achieve with the string `image/save`, but try opening your form using

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'photos.store', 'files'=> true)) }}
```

This should cause the form to have the enctype `multipart/form-data`, thus enabling file upload.